# How to copy ngRepeat content into another div?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm listing a json file using angular, like this:

html:

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    <h1>{{task.title}}</h1>
    <small>{{task.date}}</small>
    <p>{{task.details}}</p>
    <button ng-click="details($event)" data-title="{{task.title}}" data-date="{{task.date}}" data-details="{{task.details}}"></button>
</li>
```

js:

```
$scope.details = function(obj){
    var title = obj.target.getAttribute('data-title'),
        date    = obj.target.getAttribute('data-date');
    ...
}
```

I pass all content via `data-attributes`, when I click on `<button>` it calls the `ng-click` and I access all `data-attributes` via pure javascript and create a `<div>` to wrap those contents. This way is working just fine, but is there an easier way to get those values via angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much simpler and proper angular way, yes just pass `task` though the ng-click function expression and access it from your handler and say goodbye to DOM access from the controller (which is anyways bad) and data attributes:-

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    <h1>{{task.title}}</h1>
    <small>{{task.date}}</small>
    <p>{{task.details}}</p>
    <button ng-click="details(task)"></button>
</li>
```

and

```
$scope.details = function(task){
   console.log(task);
   //console.log(this.task);
}
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QMCBnv?p=preview)**

Comment: That's what I'm talking about! Thanks dude, I f**king love you!! Much much much simpler! s2